# ANTLR Parser suggestions for markup language

Tags: parsing, antlr

The current mark-up we use is demonstrated in the sections below.  It was mostly created due to flexibility, but we don't mind changing it.

**In the most simple example I can give, here is some of the mark-up:**

```
interface Serial0/0/0:1
description <<! variable, data_t1_port_size, Data T1 Port Size in kbps !>> kbps MPLS; <<!variable, data_t1_carrier_name, Data T1 Carrier Name !>>; Ckt <<! variable, data_t1_carrier_circuit_id, Data T1 Carrier Circuit ID !>>
bandwidth <<! variable, data_t1_port_size, Data T1 Port Size in kbps !>>
```

**A brief annotation of the mark-up language:**

```
interface Serial0/0/0:1 (inline static config)
description <<! variable, [variableValue], [variableDescription] !>> kbps MPLS; <<!variable, [variableValue], [variableDescription] !>>; Ckt <<! variable, [variableValue], [variableDescription] !>>
bandwidth <<! variable, [variableValue], [variableDescription] !>>
```

This is a Router configuration.
The user would enter the variableValue by filling in the value in a Web GUI
(a label displaying the variableDescription would be displayed so they know what 
they are entering).

The end goal is to parse the inline variables and be
able to generate something like this:

```
interface Serial0/0/0:1
description 1544 kbps MPLS; Verizon; Ckt 123456789
bandwidth 1544
```

My question is:
Is there a common markup language that can be used in order to do this (we can always change the templates)?

The requirements would be:

- Inline variables that can include a variable value and variable
  description
- For-each type of logic within the language (not demonstrated here,
  but it would be nice to be able to repeat a line of config some number of times).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find ANTLR too restrictive in this case. It is handy for programming languages rather for "ambiguous text".

A lot of work will have to be done. You have to decide whether this will be done in Lexer(i.e. you make it somehow context sensitive), Parser or during post processing.

For example if you decide that "interface" will be a reserved keyword in your grammar then you *must not* use the word "interface" in description section.
Which might be confusing for users. But on the other hand Lexer and Parser would be easy to implement. (Of source this problem will disapear when you force descripton to be double quoted).

So I think ANTLR will help you a lot at 1st phase. ANTLR is really handy when you have several iterations in your project and you have to refactor your parser several times.

But on the other hand some of the corner cases might be hard to sort out.

Maybe best way how to start it to prepare (collect) a bigger set of representative inputs for the parser.

Then you should decide whether the Lexer will recognize only special tags ("<>") or whether it will also support keywords. Enforcing quoted strings would make parsing much easier, but I do not know I users will be happy with it.

PS: you can also for example enforce variable names to start with "$"  (or "@") to distinguish them from anything else during Lexing.